# Endless loop with request dispatched to JspServlet on WebLogic 11g

Tags: jsp, servlets, weblogic

I have the following configuration:

**ServletA** (in my case Apache CXFserlet - but this is not important), which is matching all requests - /*.
**ServletB**, which is doing dispatch to a named servlet - "jsp" if it is available or "JspServlet" otherwise.

**ServletA** is configured so that it is forwarding to **ServletB** all JSP requests. This is working perfect.

On the other hand **ServletB** is doing forward to "org.apache.jasper.servlet.JSPServlet" if the application is running on Tomcat or to "weblogic.servlet.JSPServlet" if I'm using Oracle Weblogic.

Everything is working perfect on Tomcat.

On Weblogic, I have the following problem:
**ServletA** is forwarding to **ServletB** it forwards to `weblogic.servlet.JSPServlet`. The JSPServlet is supposed to serve the JSP but it does not. Instead of this I get to an endless loop (**ServletA -> ServletB -> JSPServlet -> ServletA -> ...**)

Does anyone have an idea what is going on inside `weblogic.servlet.JSPServlet`, and have any idea how I can get Weblogic to serve my JSP? All ideas and suggestions are welcome... I have already invested too much time in this problem without any success.

NOTES:

- Tested on Weblogic 10.3.5;
- If **ServletB** forwards to dummy servlet no loop occurs;
- Forwarding is done by using RequestDispatcher, retrieved by calling getNamedDispatcher("jsp") for Tomcat or getNamedDispatcher("JspServlet") for WebLogic.

Comment: Your CXF servlet should actually not be mapped on `/*` whenever you bundle it together with a JSP webapplication. Either it has to be mapped on a more specific URL pattern, or has to be deployed in a separate WAR.

Comment: I am more interested in the fact why Weblogic is not working as expected. I have many reasons for mapping CXF to /* and separate war is totally not an option.
Actually I can live without JSPs, but they'll do my live a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I think its the new Servlet 2.5 specs which Weblogic strictly enforces when it comes to URL mapping.

- A servlet path string that contains only the `/` (forward slash) character indicates the default servlet of the application. The servlet path resolves to the request URI minus the context path; in this case, the path resolves to null.
- A String that begins with an `*` (asterisk) specifies an extension mapping.

These changes introduce a change in behavior with the following HttpServletRequest methods:

- getPathInfo
- getServletPath

To better illustrate the change in behavior, consider the request `/abc/def.html` that resolves to ServletA:

- If `/` maps to ServletA, then `servletPath="abc/def.html"` and `pathInfo=null`.
- If `/*` maps to ServletA, then `servletPath=""` and `pathInfo="abc/def.html"`.

To ensure that the path info returned is non-null, replace all occurrences of the `/` (forward slash) servlet mapping string with `/*`.

Comment: I already did that. Actually, initially I was going with "/*" mapping and since I was desperate, I gave a try to "/" mapping, achieving the result above.
Thank you for your answer, anyway!